# React Router: Pass this.props.location to navbar component

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react application using `npx create-react-app`. I am using React Router to control routing. I need to be able to access `props.location.search` from inside my `Navbar` component. However, because `Navbar` is not a descendant of `Route` the `location` property does not get automatically passed to the Navbar. How can I get this property and pass it to the `Navbar` inside of `App.js`?

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Navbar location={LOCATION NEEDS TO BE PASSED} />
                <Container>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                </Container>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping the `Navbar` component with `withRouter` I can access the properties passed by react router.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.location.search);
    }
}

export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside you `<Navbar/>` component you can access the location using the `useLocation` hook (if navbar is a function and not a class)

```js
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

and you can access more route info from the `useLocation` hook

Comment: `Navbar` is a class component

Comment: use `withRouter` function wrapper when exporting your navbar https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter